# Convolution of monotonic positive l^2 sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, inequality, convolution

Let a is a monotonic half-infinite positive sequence in l^2. Will then the convolution a*a belong to l^2 too? Please, if the answer is positive, give a proof or sketch of proof, otherwise - a counterexample. Thank you.Emil Ivanov.

Comment: An (may be) easier question:under the above assumptions does (a*a)[n]->0 as n->Infinity ? E. Ivanov

Comment: If a belongs not only to l^2,but to l^1 too, then the convolution a*a belongs to l^1 and hence to l^2 (Cauchy-Mertens).In this case monotonousness is not necessary (positiveness is sufficient). But this is well known and is very far from the answers of the above questions. E. Ivanov.